# how to find strings enclosed with curly braces and remove them in an object?

Tags: jquery

This is the object's content to be passed:

```
var data = displayObj.data;
itemHtml = $(displayObj.template).clone();
var i=0;
var ele = itemHtml.find('[data-id]');
$(ele).attr('id',data[i].id);
itemHtml.find('[data-conversation-id]').html('{data[i].id}');
itemHtml.find('[data-conversation-user-name]').html('{data[i].name}');
itemHtml.find('[data-conversation-preview]').html('{data[i].msg}');                             
(data[i].notification > 0 ? itemHtml.find('[data-toggle-notify]').css('display', 'block'): itemHtml.find('[data-toggle-notify]').css('display', 'none'));
itemHtml.find('[data-toggle-notify]').html('{data[i].notification}');
```

> Now I'm passing the object as itemHtml elsewhere in the same page to
>   be appended to a div within **for loop**.

```
var counter = 5;
for(var i=0; i < counter;i++){
 wrapper.append(itemHtml);
 }
```

> before append, search must be made to search all strings enclosed with
>   `'{}'` thus remove the braces and also the single quote around it so
>   that they will be valid value instead.

```
html.('{data[i].name}')
```

the above to be changed to this and now this is a valid value.This is what I'm looking to do..Someone help me..

```
html.(data[i].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer turned out to be quite different, see bottom of answer:

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "in an object", but this seems like a pretty simple regex which you can practice here: http://www.regexr.com/

This would be an example of doing it in javascript

```
const re = /'{(.*?)}'/g;
const s = "html.('{data[i].name}') html.('{data[i].name}')";
console.log(s);
const s2 = s.replace(re, '$1');
console.log(s2);
```

Basically this matches all strings with `'{` followed by any characters, terminated by `}'` in a non-greedy fashion (i.e. it will match as few characters as possible in the match-any section, `.*`).

In that example I also use `/g` which will match all occurrences, but if you only need one, just drop the `g`.

---

Having looked at your jsfiddle, I think some simplification might be in order.

For a start, you can't do `var x.y = 'foo'`, that's not valid syntax. Second, your data is a string, but when you iterate over it later, I think you assume that it is two objects in an array. I don't know what dispayObj is for exactly, but I have removed it in my fixed example.

I take your data string (which I assume is meant to be JSON, so I corrected the syntax) and parse it into javascript objects. Then I iterate over the data and create some elements with jquery. I add the data attributes and also make the content of the div the value (as otherwise there is nothing to see).

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"id":8,"name":"keren"},{"id":9,"name":"rose"}]');
var body = $('#body');

for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
  var dataItem = data[i];
  var conversationId = $('<div>' + dataItem.id + '</div>').data('conversation-id', dataItem.id);
  var conversationUser = $('<div>' + dataItem.name + '</div>').data('conversation-user-name', dataItem.name);
  var dataContainer = $('<div></div>').append(conversationId, conversationUser);
  $('#body').append(dataContainer);
}
```

In an updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0cabq8rp/

Comment: search for the matched string has to be made within an object. the object is itemHtml. your answer searches through string..

Comment: The strings you need to match are the keys of the object? Perhaps make a https://jsfiddle.net/ with a fully populated itemHtml. Your above code does not execute because it references displayObj.

Comment: Ok, there are quite a lot of problems, but I will address them in an edit of my answer above.

Comment: Updated. I also think you might in the long run benefit from using a templating library like http://handlebarsjs.com/ if you are doing a lot of this kind of thing.

Comment: you got me wrong. You thought I meant the {} from JSON string? No it's not. I added them, as you can see above.

Comment: And I don't wanna opt for libraries as I'm just gonna use it once

Comment: Your example and jsfiddle are broken so it's almost impossible to determine your objective. The code I wrote seems to achieve your objective. If you wish to start with a javascript object instead of JSON that is also trivial and doesn't really change the answer other than to make data an array of objects to start with instead of a JSON string